# How to output cmb2 wysiwyg by using timber

Tags: plugins, wysiwyg

I am using cmb2 to create the custom post type, and I have a custom post type called legacy_cycle that has a metabox called challenges_one. In this metabox, there are several wysiwyg fileds.

```
    public function challenges_one_metabox(){
    $prefix = '_challenges_one_';

    $challenges_one_metabox = new_cmb2_box(array(
        'id' => $prefix . 'metabox',
        'title' => 'Challenge 1',
        'object_types' => array('legacy_cycle'),
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'show_names' => true
    ));

    $challenges_one_metabox->add_field(array(
        'name' => 'Challenge',
        'id' => $prefix .'challenge',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'options' => array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10,
            'quicktags' => false,
        ),
    ));

    $challenges_one_metabox->add_field(array(
        'name' => 'Generate Ideas',
        'id' => $prefix .'generate_ideas',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'options' => array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10,
            'quicktags' => false,
        ),
    ));

    $challenges_one_metabox->add_field(array(
        'name' => 'Gather Multiple Perspectives',
        'id' => $prefix .'gather_multiple_perspectives',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'options' => array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10,
            'quicktags' => false,
        ),
    ));

    $challenges_one_metabox->add_field(array(
        'name' => 'Research and Revise',
        'id' => $prefix .'research_and_revise',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'options' => array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10,
            'quicktags' => false,
        ),
    ));

    $challenges_one_metabox->add_field(array(
        'name' => 'Test Your Mettle',
        'id' => $prefix .'test_your_mettle',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'options' => array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10,
            'quicktags' => false,
        ),
    ));

    $challenges_one_metabox->add_field(array(
        'name' => 'Go Public',
        'id' => $prefix .'go_public',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'options' => array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10,
            'quicktags' => false,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Then I am using Timber as theme tool to display the input.

```
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="challenge1">
                <h4> Challenge </h4>
                <div>
                    <p>{{post._challenges_one_challenge}}</p>
                </div>
                <h4> Generate Ideas </h4>
                <div>
                    <p>{{post._challenges_one_generate_ideas}}</p>
                </div>
                <h4> Gather Perspectives </h4>
                <div>
                    <p>{{post._challenges_one_gather_multiple_perspectives}}</p>
                </div>
                <h4> Research & Revise </h4>
                <div>
                    <p>{{post._challenges_one_research_and_revise}}</p>
                </div>
                <h4>Test Your Mettle</h4>
                <div>
                    <p>{{post._challenges_one_test_your_mettle}}</p>
                </div>
                <h4> Go Public </h4>
                <div>
                    <p>{{post._challenges_one_go_public}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However, the wysiwyg field could not work properly. It is fine if it only contains text or image, but it only output the following information when I insert a youtube video in the wysiwyg editor under the custom post type.

" [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MS91knuzoOA[/embed]"
I tried to use post.get_filed('my_wysiwig'), but it did not work.

I am wondering how I could output the field correctly? much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, please consider showing your code. As it's written it seems very localised and/or more of a plugin/theme support case all of which are against the rules. However "I'm doing `x`, expecting `y` but getting `z` is ok providing you show your working.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Just updated the question. Sorry I am relatively new to the forum....

Comment: How are you inserting the video in the editor? If you just literally type the YouTube address, does it work? Do you know where the `[embed]` tags are coming from?

Comment: I inserted the video through the wysiwyg editor, and the video shows up in the editor when in the dashboard view, but I am not sure why wordpress add [embed] tag to the database...i figured it out, :) thanks for answering anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out through this post..[Applying oembed filters to WYSIWYG field](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/applying-oembed-filters-to-wysiwyg-field)

My solution by using timber/twig is to get the data in the single.php, and here is the code:

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'my_wysiswg', true);
$post_meta = $wp_embed->autoembed( $post_meta );
$post_meta = $wp_embed->run_shortcode( $post_meta );
$post_meta = do_shortcode( $post_meta );
$post_meta = wpautop( $post_meta );
$post->my_wysiswyg = $post_meta;
```

Then I can print the video in the single-custom-post-type.twig by using {{post.my_wysiswyg}}